Measurable selection for the mean value theorem
When we use the mean value theorem we come across the problem of measurability of the argument. The problem is somehow like that:
Let $f:\Omega\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Caratheodory function (i.e. $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for a.a. $x\in\Omega$, and $f(\cdot,s)$ is measurable for all $s\in [0,1]$). Here $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a domain. Define the multifunction:
$$F:\Omega\rightrightarrows [0,1],\ F(x)=\left\{y\in [0,1]\ |\ f(x,y)=\max_{s\in [0,1]} f(x,s)\right\}$$
Is it true that there is a measurable selector $\phi:X\to [0,1]$ such that:
$$\max_{s\in [0,1]}f(x,s)=f(x,\phi(x)),\ \forall\ x\in\Omega$$
?

See my answer here for a reference to the question you have asked. This does not have anything to do with the mean value theorem though.

Thank you very much. Yes, you are right. I just wanted to mention that I need this kind of result because of the mean value theorem in studying some pde's with variational methods.
